# Compiling and installing pyactivemq on osx

Tags: python, macos, activemq-classic, macports

I'm having a hardtime trying to install pyactivemq (link) on my osx leopard. Following a tutorial (in portuguese) on [compiling it](http://www.semtexgirl.net/2009/07/24/compilando-o-pyactivemq-activemq-cpp-no-mac-os-x-leopard/) ends up ok, but when I run the tests i receive only a crypt message:

```
Fatal Python error: Interpreter not initialized (version mismatch?)
```

There is not much information on the web about using pyactivemq on osx, but what I could find is that is something related to wrong linking when boost compiles.

I'm running:

- Mac OS 10.5.8
- MacPorts 1.8.2
- APR 1.3.9
- Xcode 3.1.4
- Boost 1.41.0 (installing for python 2.5)
- Activemq-cpp 2.2.6
- pyactivemq 0.1.0

If someone has any info on this it would be helpful knowing that I'm using `python 2.5` installed from macports

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Did you install it from MacPorts?

Comment: 2.5, yes, it was installed from macports